# Magisk v23 with Android Studio

Tags: android-emulator, magisk, xposed-framework, android-studio, lsposed

I am trying to install LSPosed [1], but it requires Magisk v23 [2]. I tried to
install Magisk v23 using the instruction here [3], but I get this result:

```
- Device platform: x86
- Installing: 23.0 (23000)
- Copying image to cache
! Process error
! Installation failed
```

In one of the steps, the instructions say you can use one of these three
commands:

```
patch.bat
patch.bat manager
patch.bat canary
```

I ran through all the steps three times, each time using a different command
above, none of them worked. Note, I am able to install the older Magisk v21.4,
but nothing newer. I am using Android Studio with a Virtual Device:

```
API 27
Android 8.1
```

I have seen other people show screenshots of this working, but they refuse to
explain how they were able to do it. Does anyone know how to get this working?

1. https://github.com/LSPosed/LSPosed
2. https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk
3. https://github.com/shakalaca/MagiskOnEmulator

Comment: Please include all the commands you have executed and at which command you are getting the error.

Comment: https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/guides.html#root-directory-overlay-system

Answer (score 1):

Okay so you have magisk 21.x working...

```
su
echo $PATH
```

Copy the output string.

Use a file explorer with root access and

1. Head over to /
2. Edit init.environ.rc by adding "export PATH <that copied string>" as the first line of the file.
3. Now, if there is no sbin folder in / , make one
4. Now from magisk manager (or whatever way), upgrade to Magisk 23

Comment: I dont like this at all. I should be able to just install v23 directly. It appears that is what other people are doing

Comment: I totally agree with you but so far this is how  i managed the stuff for myself.... ofcourse not a solution but a working "workaround" .